# How can Genetic Algorithms solve task-allocation to worker problems

Tags: optimization, genetic-algorithm

I am trying to understand how genetic algorithms can be used to solve task-allocation to worker problems, as described in a paper called `Solving Task Allocation to the Worker Using Genetic Algorithm`.

As an example, I have the following table which represents workers and how long they take to perform a task.

```
## Task number going left to right
## Worker number going down

# | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
1 | 2 | 5 | 7 | 1 | 6 |
2 | 5 | 4 | 9 | 2 | 4 |
3 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 6 |
4 | 7 | 1 | 8 | 9 | 2 |
5 | 3 | 2 | 6 | 1 | 8 |
```

The problem involves selecting the worker which performs the task the quickest, for each task. I have read that the genetic algorithm consists of 5 key phases: Initial population, fitness function, selection, crossover(mating) and mutation.

I understand that the table represents the initial population of individuals represented by chromosomes. Inside the chromosomes contains genes.

What I don't understand are the other phases and how this would solve the problem. How are the other phases I mentioned above (fitness function, selection, crossover(mating) and mutation) relevant to solving this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fitness function is a measure of the quality of a solution. You use this to discriminate between solutions e.g a solution with fitness 10 is better than solution with fitness 5 in a maximisation problem

Once you know the fitness of each solution, you can select better solutions and avoid worse solutions. There are many types of selection methods e.g tournament selection which selects the best of randomly selected solutions

crossover is used to create new offspring solution from a the selected solutions. The thinking behind this is to combine the good genes in better solutions to create even better solutions

Mutation is just to create a bit of randomness in the solution. This can be especially useful when solutions get too similar and therefore gets trapped in what is called local optimal.

See https://github.com/mayoayodele/Permutation-GA for an easy implementation you can look at

Mutation is not done often because it can be quite disruptive, it is common to set the probability to 1/problem_size. From the permutation GA code above using a simple fitness

```
for (int i = 0; i < Solution.size(); i++) {
            fitness += (i * Solution.get(i));

        }
```

An offspring is produced from the following parents as follows,

```
Parent1 [3, 0, 7, 1, 8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 2]
Fitness 219
Parent2 [2, 7, 0, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 1, 3]
Fitness 215
offspring [3, 0, 7, 1, 8, 9, 4, 5, 2, 6]
Fitness 223
```

in the example above, the offspring is better than both parents but this is not always the case e.g

```
Parent1 [9, 3, 1, 2, 8, 4, 7, 0, 5, 6]
Fitness 199
Parent2 [0, 4, 8, 3, 6, 1, 2, 7, 9, 5]
Fitness 236
offspring [9, 3, 1, 2, 8, 0, 4, 6, 7, 5]
Fitness 210
```

For mutation see below example

```
offspring [3, 5, 2, 1, 9, 8, 0, 4, 7, 6]
Fitness 226
offspring after mutation [3, 5, 2, 1, 9, 0, 4, 7, 8, 6]
Fitness 239
```

In the above example, mutation improved the fitness but in the one below it didn't

```
offspring [6, 8, 3, 0, 4, 1, 7, 5, 2, 9]
209
offspring after mutation [6, 8, 3, 0, 4, 1, 7, 5, 9, 2]
202
```

Comment: Would you be able to provide a visual example of how after the initial generation have been mutated, how the offspring produced can then be used to find alternative new solutions based on their fitness? This is the part I am struggling to understand.

Comment: @Corbuk I added some more information in the answer presented above, hope it helps. Best way is just try running some code and print out what happens at each generation to see how it works. GA will not always give you the optimal but it will often give you good solutions

Comment: Thank you for your reply. One last question, How would I represent the chromosome so that I can identify the task I am referring to, the worker which is assigned to it and show how long it would take a worker to perform the task? (I believe that is the information I would need in order to calculate fitness, apply crossover and mutation, correct me if I am wrong)

Answer (score 0):

A vector of random workers in line is a potential solution. (Initialization)
To see how log they perform the task you use the objective function (the fitness function is the way each solution is assessed). Basically you assess each vector of workers the time they need by using the table you provided.

For crossover, you take 2 (random) solutions and you mix their characteristics. There are various ways to do so in the literature.

For mutation, you pick (also randomly) 1 solution at a time and you alter one of their characteristics.

you evaluate the new solutions, and you keep the N best solution ever found so far for the next iteration.